# jquery mobile for BlackBerry z10 image link zooms

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, blackberry-10

I'm developing a mobile app for BlackBerry z10 with jquery mobile for BlackBerry 10. I used an image as a button, but when I double tap the image, the whole app zooms.

This is the code I used:

```
<a href="#frm_page1" onClick="show()"><img src="images/buttons/page1.png"/></a>
```

but the other images are not zooming at all (image with no links).

What seems to be the problem while I'm having this code here:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=0, initial-scale=0.45, maximum-scale=0.45, minimum-scale=0.45, width=device-width, height=device-height" charset="UTF-8"/>
```

Can anyone help me to get rid of this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is one method that I found, Please check it:

```
<meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, user-scalable=no/">
```

Another method would be:

```
<script>
var meta = document.createElement("meta");
meta.setAttribute('name','viewport');
meta.setAttribute('content','initial-scale='+ (1/window.devicePixelRatio) + ',user-scalable=no');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a virtual click event. Maybe it is because the click event is meant for mouse click, and the BB Z10 is a touch screen device where you tap to select something.

```
<a href="#frm_page1" id="show_something"><img src="images/buttons/page1.png"/></a>
```

$("#show_something").on("vclick",function(e){

// show something code

e.preventDefault();

});